# ZenTest not working with RSpec 2.7 and Rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, autotest, zentest

I've basically followed [this RSpec guide](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/autotest) on my simple Rails app, but when I run autotest I get

```
$ autotest
(Not running features.  To run features in autotest, set AUTOFEATURE=true.)
loading autotest/rails_rspec2
bundle exec /Users/darth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby -S /Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/bin/rspec --tty '/Users/darth/projects/checkin/spec/models/player_spec.rb'
/Users/darth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- /Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/bin/rspec (LoadError)
```

When I look at the gem directory, it looks like there's `exe` folder instead of `bin`

```
$ ls ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/
README.md exe       features  lib       spec

$ ls ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.7.0/exe/
autospec rspec
```

And this is my Gemfile

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'  
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'ZenTest', '~> 4.4.2'
  gem 'autotest-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/478

Comment: Also - just released rspec-core-2.7.1, which fixes this.